# after upgrading to 12.04 capitel EVDO modem is not working

Tags: 12.04, connection, usb-modem

I have a BSNL EVDO modem which was working fine on ubuntu 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10. Yesterday after upgrading to 12.04 via update manager, it is not working and not even detected on the network manager. I downloaded ISO (64 bit) and tried a fresh install after formatting the partition, with no effect.

I am surprised that the update broke it, please help !!!!

PS :: tested and ensured it is still working fine on windows

Here is the output on `/var/log/usb_modeswitch.log`

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Sat Apr 28 12:13:18 2012

Using global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

Raw args from udev: /2-1.2:1.0

Bus ID for device not given by udev.
 Trying to determine it from kernel name (2-1.2:1.0) ...
Using top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2

SCSI dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2
Warning: SCSI attribute "vendor" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "model" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "rev" not readable.
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
  idVendor  1c9e
  idProduct 9e00
  manufacturer  Qualcomm, Incorporated
  product   USB MMC Storage
  serial    000000000002
  bNumConfigurations    1
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
Found packed config collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
Searching entries named: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/1c9e:9e00*
Searching overriding entries named: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e:9e00*
SCSI attributes not needed, moving on.

Extracting config 1c9e:9e00 from collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
config: TargetClass set to ff
Driver module is "option", ID path is /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1
! matched, now switching
Command to be run:
/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -I -W -D -s 20 -c /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg -u -1   -v 1c9e -p 9e00 2>&1

Verbose debug output of usb_modeswitch and libusb follows
(Note that some USB errors are expected in the process)
--------------------------------

tail: /var/log/usb_modeswitch.log: file truncated


USB_ModeSwitch log from Sat Apr 28 12:13:20 2012

Using global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

Raw args from udev: /2-1.2:1.5

Bus ID for device not given by udev.
 Trying to determine it from kernel name (2-1.2:1.5) ...
Using top device dir /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2

USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.

SCSI dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2
Warning: SCSI attribute "vendor" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "model" not readable.
Warning: SCSI attribute "rev" not readable.
----------------
USB values from sysfs:
  idVendor  1c9e
  idProduct 9e00
  manufacturer  Qualcomm, Incorporated
  product   Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
  serial    (null)
  bNumConfigurations    1
----------------
bNumConfigurations is 1 - don't check for active configuration
Found packed config collection /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
Searching entries named: /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/1c9e:9e00*
Searching overriding entries named: /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e:9e00*
SCSI attributes not needed, moving on.

Reading config file: /run/usb_modeswitch/current_cfg

 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 1.2.3 (C) Josua Dietze 2012
 * Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x1c9e
DefaultProduct= 0x9e00
TargetVendor=   not set
TargetProduct=  not set
TargetClass=    0xff
TargetProductList=""

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=0
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
QisdaMode=0
GCTMode=0
KobilMode=0
SequansMode=0
MobileActionMode=0
CiscoMode=0
MessageEndpoint=  not set
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000606f50402527000000000000000000000"
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set

InquireDevice disabled
Success check enabled, max. wait time 20 seconds
System integration mode enabled


Looking for target devices ...
 No devices in target mode or class found
Looking for default devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 1c9e:9e00
   found matching vendor ID
   found matching product ID
   target class ff not matching
   adding device
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0139
  searching devices, found USB ID 058f:a014
  searching devices, found USB ID 0cf3:3005
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 007 on bus 002 ...
Skipping the check for the current configuration
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x08 (out) and 0x87 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
     Product: USB MMC Storage
  Serial No.: 000000000002
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver found ("usb-storage")
 OK, driver "usb-storage" detached
Setting up communication with interface 0
Using endpoint 0x08 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x08 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Resetting response endpoint 0x87
Resetting message endpoint 0x08
 Device is gone, skipping any further commands

Checking for mode switch (max. 20 times, once per second) ...
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0139
  searching devices, found USB ID 058f:a014
  searching devices, found USB ID 0cf3:3005
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Searching for target devices ...
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 1c9e:9e00
   found matching vendor ID
   found matching product ID
   target class ff matching
   adding device
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
  searching devices, found USB ID 0bda:0139
  searching devices, found USB ID 058f:a014
  searching devices, found USB ID 0cf3:3005
  searching devices, found USB ID 8087:0024
  searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002

Found target device, now opening

Found target device 008 on bus 002

Target device description data
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
     Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
 Found correct target device

Mode switch succeeded. Bye.

ok:1c9e:9e00
--------------------------------
(end of usb_modeswitch output)
Checking success of mode switch for max. 20 seconds ... Reading attributes ...
USB dir exists: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2
Warning: USB attribute "serial" not readable.
 All attributes matched
Mode switching was successful, found 1c9e:9e00 (Qualcomm, Incorporated: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM)Now checking for bound driver ...
 no driver has bound to interface 0 yet
Device not in "bind_list" yet, bind it now
 modprobe not foundModule loader is (null)
Can't do anymore without module loader; get "modtools"!
 driver binding failed
Checking for AVOID_RESET_QUIRK kernel attribute
 AVOID_RESET_QUIRK activated

All done, exiting
```

dmesg entries

```
[   43.068088] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[   43.189986] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[   43.190211] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[   43.190275] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   43.190276] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[   43.266543] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   44.188822] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   44.195201] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[   44.195414] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[   44.195487] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[   44.292778] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[   44.292786] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[   44.292789] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[   44.448614] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[   44.448622] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[   44.448624] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[   44.680705] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   45.903611] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[   45.998999] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.5
[   46.996804] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   46.997717] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   47.003776] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  131.624851] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  137.005910] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[  137.101084] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[  138.098644] scsi 9:0:0:0: CD-ROM            USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  138.106114] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[  138.106531] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  138.106811] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[  138.198600] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  138.198627] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  138.198635] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  138.456257] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  139.677709] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[  139.774058] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.5
[  140.774624] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  140.777200] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  140.783764] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  156.867977] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  216.594721] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[  216.689732] scsi11 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[  217.687395] scsi 11:0:0:0: CD-ROM            USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  217.694689] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[  217.695092] sr 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  217.695397] sr 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[  217.787287] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  217.787312] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  217.787321] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  218.117857] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  219.338270] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[  219.433452] scsi12 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.5
[  220.430998] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  220.432676] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  220.438016] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: i answered it here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/156270/how-to-connect-my-cdma-modem/285410#285410

Answer (score 1):

CAPITEL Modem working in my desktop after Upgrade.
See this dmesg output from Desktop.  My fresh installation in netbook is not working!!

```
manu@pranavam:~$ dmesg | tail -10
[ 3523.511872] usbserial_generic 4-1:1.3: generic converter detected
[ 3523.512056] usb 4-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[ 3523.512145] usbserial_generic 4-1:1.4: generic converter detected
[ 3523.512291] usb 4-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[ 3523.512481] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-1:1.5
[ 3524.516048] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3524.516620] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 3524.527040] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3524.603584] show_signal_msg: 27 callbacks suppressed
[ 3524.603588] usb_modeswitch_[3741]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f10e7e30a7e sp 00007fffa4aaf8c0 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7f10e7dc2000+1b3000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal from Applications -> Accessories (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Then type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

**Note:** It will ask to type SUDO Passwrod, type your admin account password. Command prompt will not show your password, just type it and press enter key.

At the bottom of the file, make two new lines, like this:

```
usbserial
option
```

Then close the editor program and save it. Reboot the computer and hopefully you’ll be right from now on!

**Credit:** Maduka Jayalath , Original Post = [Micromax MMX 310G Data Card is not being recognized as a modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130488/micromax-mmx-310g-data-card-not-working-in-12-04)