# Micromax MMX 310G Data Card is not being recognized as a modem

Tags: usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

When I plug My USB Mobile Broadband Modem, it is detected as a storage disk. It does not switch its mode to Modem. The modem is Micromax MMX310G 3G.

Comment: Which is your modem?

Comment: It is a Micromax MMx310G.

Comment: i also have a micromaxmmx353g. it does not run in ubuntu 2.04,thogh it runs well on previous version. i think the problem is with the kernel. and ubunutu 12.04 doesnt run sakis 3g also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download `sakis3g` script from following site http://www.snowguide.gr/gnu-linux-corner/raspberry-pi-raspbian/117-sakis3g-script
2. save it in home folder and extract it.
3. go to properties and in permission check allow it as executable.
4. open terminal and type  `chmod a+x ./sakis3g`   and enter .
5. now just type `./sakis3g` and enter .
6. a sakis3g window will open .
7. just go through it what you think you should enter.
8. Choose APN for your particular connection.(www for vodafone for example.)
9. You can see that the modem is being detected.
10. when you will be asked to enter user name just cancel it.It will show to be failed but don't worry.It will not cause anything.
11. now you will see that there is an option for mobile broadband connection.click on it and it will be connected.

You are done.

**Few things**: When you starting your computer and connecting modem for the first time after starting computer you have to go through 5 to 12 .But after that if you disconnect your modem and connect it again it will automatically show your modem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you perhaps had a look at this guide?

[How to run micromax MMX 310G in ubuntu](http://micromax-mmx-310g.blogspot.com/)

There is also another guide on the Ubuntu Forums here:

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1695102)

Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of your **mobile settings** 
your mobile is in mas storage mode .change change in to **PC suite mode**

- Change your mobile phone settings
- active data cable  for **PC suite**
  or contact your costumer care of your SIM card servicer

Comment: It is not mobile but mobile broadband by usb modem.

Comment: Sir Beeju.You are absolutely Right.It is a mobile broadband Modem.It was detected in 11.04 and 11.10.But it wont be detected in 12.04.I think it is a bug.

Comment: I at last got the answer.Use sakis3g script(www.sakis3g.org).It worked perfectly

Comment: @shmzkm, Please post that as an answer and mark that as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal from Applications -> Accessories. Type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modules
```

At the bottom of the file, make two new lines, like this:

```
usbserial
option
```

Then close the editor program and save it. Reboot the computer and hopefully you’ll be right from now on!