# Unable to connect USB modem

Tags: 12.10, internet, usb-modem

I want to configure my DLink USB modem to Ubuntu 12.10, it does not detect it.

Comment: You may have to contact the manufacturer to know if a driver is needed and available. Also take a look at [Enabling or Installing D-Link DWM 156 broadband modem?](http://askubuntu.com/q/168663/25656)

Answer (score 0):

> Open up a terminal from Applications -> Accessories. Type:
>
> ```
> gksu gedit /etc/modules
> ```
>
> At the bottom of the file, make two new lines, like this:
>
> usbserial
>
> option
>
> Then close the editor program and save it. Reboot the computer[.]

I found this solution in [Maduka Jayalath's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/131326/22949) to [Micromax MMX 310G Data Card is not being recognized as a modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130488/micromax-mmx-310g-data-card-is-not-being-recognized-as-a-modem).