# How to connect my CDMA modem?

Tags: usb-modem, cdma

I am using a CDMA 1x modem in india. I is extremely slow but comes with a unlimited package. So thats why I cannot leave it. I tried to configure it using network manager but it didnt work. The manufacturer is Linktop. The model number is 3197

The output of lsusb is-
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05c6:3197 Qualcomm, Inc CDMA Wireless Modem/Phone

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You should contact the manufacturers with details of your operating system (which you haven't mentioned at all).

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 right now. Tell me the other things you want to know and I will inform you

Comment: good afternoon, I was going through your instructions, but in step 5, it writes this:
rmmod: ERROR: Module usbserial is in use by: option isb_wwan.

Answer (score 1):

1- Create a new File Named `0408:ea25` in `/etc/usb.modeswitch.d` and put Config Data:

```
sudo nano /etc/usb.modeswitch.d/0408:ea25
```

- Copy the Below Text

`DefaultVendor=  0x0408
    DefaultProduct= 0xea25
    TargetVendor=   0x0408
    TargetProduct=  0xea26
    MessageContent="5553424312345678000000000000061b004600000000000000000000000000"
    CheckSuccess=20`

2- Add a new Rule to modeswitch rules:

```
sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

- copy this line @ the end of the file:

  `ATTRS{idVendor}=="0408", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea25", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"`

3- Restart udev

```
sudo service udev restart
```

4- Add Detection Command to modprobe

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/mobily-lte.conf
```

- copy the below text

  `options usbserial vendor=0x0408 product=0xea26`

5- Remove and Add `usbserial` config, This will Detect the Device

```
sudo rmmod usbserial
sudo modprobe usbserial
```

6- Configure a new Connection in Network Manager

[For more Information and Visual Gudie Visit this Post I made.](http://saleh360.blogspot.com/2013/04/mobily-4g-lte-usb-modem-workaround.html)